# Formatting in python(Kivy) like in Stack overflow

Tags: python, kivy

My issue is that I would like to take input text with formatting like you would use when creating a Stackoverflow post and reformat it into the required text string.  The best way I can think is to give an example....

```
# This is the input string
Hello **there**, how are **you**
```

```
# This is the intended output string
Hello [font=Nunito-Black.ttf]there[/font], how are [font=Nunito-Black.ttf]you[/font]
```

SO the ** is replaced by a different string that has an opening and a closing part but also needs to work as many times as needed for any string.  (As seen 2 times in the example)

I have tried to use a variable to record if the ** in need of replacing is an opening or a closing part, but haven't managed to get a function to work yet, hence it being incomplete

I think replacing the correct ** is hard because I have been trying to use index which will only return the position of the 1st occurrence in the string

**My attempt as of now**

```
def formatting_text(input_text):
        if input_text:
            if '**' in input_text:
                d = '**'
                for line in input_text:
                    s = [e+d for e in line.split(d) if e]
                count = 0
                for y in s:
                    if y == '**' and count == 0:
                        s.index(y)
                        # replace with required part

            return output_text
        return input_text
```

**I have tried to find this answer so I'm sorry if has already been asked but I have had no luck finding it and don't know what to search**

Of course thank you for any help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A general solution for your case,

### Using `re`

```py
import re


def formatting_text(input_text, special_char, left_repl, right_repl):
    # Define re pattern.
    RE_PATTERN = f"[{special_char}].\w+.[{special_char}]"

    for word in re.findall(RE_PATTERN, input_text):
        # Re-assign with replacement with the parts.
        new_word = left_repl+word.strip(special_char)+right_repl
        input_text = input_text.replace(word, new_word)
    return input_text


print(formatting_text("Hello **there**, how are **you**", "**", "[font=Nunito-Black.ttf]", "[/font]"))
```

### Without using `re`

```py
def formatting_text(input_text, special_char, left_repl, right_repl):
    while True:
        # Replace the left part.
        input_text = input_text.replace(special_char, left_repl, 1)
        # Replace the right part.
        input_text = input_text.replace(special_char, right_repl, 1)
        if input_text.find(special_char) == -1:
            # Nothing found, time to stop.
            break
    return input_text


print(formatting_text("Hello **there**, how are **you**", "**", "[font=Nunito-Black.ttf]", "[/font]"))
```

---

However the above solution should work for other `special_char` like `__`, `*`, `<` etc. But if you want to just make it bold only, you may prefer `kivy`'s bold markdown for label i.e. `[b]` and escape `[/b]`.

Comment: Thank you very much, the reason I didn't use [b] and [/b] was because it didn't change the text in my case, but since the [font] did work but crashed when the closing bracket was deleted in the input, as it was also being displayed in a label, I thought just swapping them via a function would work.  It is also nicer to type **.
Thank you for a solution though

Comment: In order to use different properties of any font you need to [`register`](https://kivy.org/doc/stable/api-kivy.core.text.html#kivy.core.text.LabelBase.register) that font-family.

Answer (score 1):

So the formatting stack overflow uses is markdown, implemented in javascript. If you just want the single case to be formatted then you can see an implementation [here](https://github.com/Python-Markdown/markdown/blob/eff6c3a0415cb63bc0b38c29b5a7f584619e3c1c/markdown/inlinepatterns.py#L118) where they use regex to find the matches and then just iterate through them.

```
STRONG_RE = r'(\*{2})(.+?)\1'
```

I would recommend against re-implementing an entire markdown solution yourself when you can just [import one](https://github.com/Python-Markdown/markdown#documentation).